# SMBIOS - Get SPD (Serial Presence Detect) Modules Information C#

Tags: c#

I searched a lot but did not find any working codes getting SPD tables information via C#. Out there there are lots of softwares which get this info but HOW?

[image]

as shown in the image, for RAM devices, you can see Manufacture's name which can not be retrieve at all by WMI etc

If there is a DLL for using in C# will be perfect also

After some Research  found this:

https://github.com/sapozhnikovay/SMBIOS

but it can not read table 17 to get memory device information.

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59257760-3db9-49e7-b575-36ca98e660cc/ram-manufacturer-info?forum=Vsexpressvcs)?

Comment: @jstreet thanks, but yes I searched a lot and I saw you link some days ago. But it uses WMI which does not work the same way I need.

Comment: That code snippet returns the manufacturer's name, which you mentioned explicitly. What does not work the same way you need?

Comment: @jstreet with WMI you can return manufacture or Type of Ram, but it will always null!

Comment: I tried that snippet and got good information (not nulls), like Manufacturer, capacity, clock speed, part number, serial number, etc... Did you try it?

Comment: @jstreet just try on several systems and you will get i'm right. WMI can not detect all types RAMs

Comment: Use P/Invoke and do it the C++ way. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227171/how-to-get-memory-information-ram-type-e-g-ddr-ddr2-ddr3-with-wmi-c) question.

Answer (score 4):

Once I was researching about this, you need to get this information through **SMBUS** (not SMBIOS). But you need to create a driver (WDM in C/C++) to access this information.

Comment: if there is a dll for using in C# will be perfect also.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added `System.Management` as a reference.

Here is a string that will return almost any information you want from the component :

```
private string getComponent(string hwClass, string syntax)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hwClass);
        foreach (ManagementObject mj in mos.Get())
        {
            return Convert.ToString(mj[syntax]);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Using the string would look like this, say on a button click :

```
label1.Text = getComponent("Win32_PhysicalMemory", "SerialNumber");
```

I tested it and it returned a serial number, you can also look at the list of things you can put in like manufacturer, name, capacity etc.

I got all of this information from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rou471Evuzc).

You can find all of the devices and their properties [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347.aspx) (CPU, GPU, etc.)

Comment: You won't be able to get Type of memory device or its manufacture exact name at all using WMI.

Comment: @Stranger  I tested the manufacturer and it worked fine. Here is an msdn link to the syntax for "PhyscialMemory" : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347(v=vs.85).aspx. In here you can find the "MemoryType" syntax, which returns a number, it tells you what number corresponds with the type of memory. For example, 24 = DDR3, 25 = FBD2 my PC returns 26 (which I'm assuming is the number for DDR4 because the documentation isn't updated yet). So you could check these numbers and make it correspond to a memory type with an IF statement. By the way I used "SMBIOSMemoryType" to get the value

Comment: In my laptop even on my PC, `MemoryType` will return 0 and also `SMBIOSMemoryType` can not be found.

Comment: Does any other application like "CPU-Z" return the correct memory type?

Comment: yes, they always return correct values in all systems.